# Returning a function of unknown name from within a function

Tags: python, string, return, exec

```
code = "def foo(): return 'bar'"

def lol(code):
    exec code
    return foo

a = lol(code)
print a()
```

This works normally, but the problem starts when we don't know what the function in the string is called. If I can guarantee that the code will be small, with a single function, how can I return that function?

One solution I thought of was just requiring the function be called 'foo' etc, so I can just return  that, but it feels ugly.

Thoughts?

Comment: Using `exec` for dynamic code generation is generally frowned upon. I would redesign the code in a way that it does not need `exec`.

Comment: I can't think of another way to evaluate a string into Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by explicitly specifying dictionaries `exec` should use for the global and local execution context. Afterwards the one used for locals should have a single entry for the function object, which can be returned without knowing its name since it should be the only item defined in the dictionary:

```
from textwrap import dedent
import types

def lol(code):
    globals_ = {"__builtins__": None}  # no built-ins for safety
    locals_ = {}

    exec(code, globals_, locals_)

    if len(locals_) != 1:
        raise ValueError("code didn't define exactly one item")
    value = locals_.popitem()[1]  # get value of the one item defined
    if type(value) != types.FunctionType:
        raise ValueError("code didn't define a function")

    return value  # return function object that was defined

my_code = dedent("""
    def foo():
        return 'bar'
""")

a = lol(my_code)
print(a())
```

Comment: Should this have the same output on both Python verisons?

Comment: You'd have to change the last line to `print(a())` because `print` is a function in Python 3, not a statement, but otherwise it works the same in both versions. I intentionally used the tuple form of `exec` because it provides compatibility with Python 3.

Comment: Do you know any way I could handle if the string of code contained more than one function?

Comment: In that case you'd need some way of telling them apart, especially because they'll be in random order in the `locals_` dictionary after the `exec`. Just requiring the function(s) of interest to have some predefined name(s) would probably be the best approach (and is a fairly common plug-in architecture).